# JS: Function vs Class differences

Tags: javascript

I've always relied on functions but I am not trying to understand the differences between classes and functions.  Are there a difference between these two in instantiating a Node?  When logging them in console, they seem to log the same but I am trying to see if there's anything I am not seeing that is different.

```
function Node(data, left, right) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
let foo = new Node(55);

----------
class Node {
   constructor(data,left,right) {
      this.node = data;
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
   }
}
let foo = new Node(55);
```

Comment: No, not really. `class` is basically syntatic sugar.

Comment: Introducing `class` into the spec was more about providing a bridge to other OO languages to make it more accessible. Functionally there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class Syntax is basically just syntactic sugar. So it's the same. However you must invoke the class with `new` while you could call the Constructor Function without.

Comment: thanks @lux .  How do you call the function without `new`?  I tried removing `new` in my example and the variable `foo` is undefined

Comment: It's undefined because the function doesn't return anything. If `function Node` had a `return` statement, then `foo` would be defined.

Comment: You can do `const obj = {}; Node.call(obj, 55)` and then `obj.data` will be 55.